# Laravel: What kind of event is triggered when a user becomes online? (echo and broadcasting)

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-echo

I am bundling a Laravel application as a web service for mobile application. I need to know which users are online at any moment, hence I am using Laravel-echo and Laravel-echo-server and Redis and Socket.io to do this. I am beginner in echo/broadcasting and this is the first time I am dealing with such issue.

From what I see on different tutorials, I need to create private or public channels and appropriate events must be fired inside the channels.

I have seen different tutorials but I still cannot fully understand it. The problem is I don't know how to detect if some one is online or not. When a user becomes online, I can detect it, But I can't find out if it is offline via disconnecting the internet or turning off the mobile or etc, and what events on server side must be fired.

I would be appreciated for any help.
Thanks in advance.

Comment: I'm currently trying to achieve the same. I'm trying to make it with this : https://github.com/tlaverdure/laravel-echo-server#presence-channels
Look like we can trigger event on subscribe and unsubscribing server side with laravel-echo-server. I did not make it happen yet.

Comment: @ElieMorin Thanks

Comment: @ElieMorin The example https://webmobtuts.com/backend-development/demonstrating-laravel-echo-socket-io-and-redis-with-real-world-example/ is useful. It shows how many people are visiting a page right now. Sounds it uses presence. I think it is good for our problem

Comment: I'll give a try to this in a near future: https://docs.beyondco.de/laravel-websockets/1.0/getting-started/introduction.html It replace laravel-echo-server (javascript based) with a php websocket. They show how to make custom handler and it say we can use Pusher function. So we could retrieve all users in a presence channel like they do on this question https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44077177/laravel-broadcast-channels-check-connections

Comment: @ElieMorin What if I don't want to use pusher? can I still ise this?

Comment: I did not tried it yet, but it say that it mime pusher. It is not pusher. So you can use what is pusher's compatible.

Comment: Look at this, https://freek.dev/1228-introducing-laravel-websockets-an-easy-to-use-websocket-server-implemented-in-php